# How can I prevent a nested HTML div element from expanding beyond the screen height?

Tags: html, css

I have a div element nested within several levels of other div elements, and I want to ensure that the content does not get displayed beyond the screen height, but allows scrolling within that div instead.  There are a lot of similar questions to this, but none of the ones I've found seem to apply to arbitrary levels of nested divs.  I'm trying to do this all with HTML/CSS and no hard-coded pixel values.

With two levels I've been able to achieve the desired behavior:

```html
<html style="height:100%; font-size:50px;">
  <body style="height:100%; margin:0;">
    <div style="width:50%; height:100%; background:green; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
      1
      <div style="width:50%; height:100%; background:blue; overflow:auto;">
        2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I can't get the same behavior with three or more levels:

```html
<html style="height:100%; font-size:50px;">
  <body style="height:100%; margin:0;">
    <div style="width:50%; height:100%; background:red; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
      1
      <div style="width:50%; height:100%; background:green; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
        2
        <div style="width:50%; height:100%; background:blue; overflow:auto;">
          3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to keep everything within the screen height for an arbitrary number of nested div levels, with the scrolling only at the deepest level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with flex items having a minimum height/width (depends on the direction) equal to content.

---

**First example**

The blue element fits inside it's parent because by default it is set to **shrink-to-fit** `flex-shrink:1;` Why this is important ? because it's not the only child.

`overflow:auto` makes the element ignore it's content, look for a height limit then add a scrollbar

---

**Second example**

The blue element fits inside the green element as expected, but the green element doesn't fit inside the red element, **Why ?**

the green element is a flex item so everything said above applies to it as well, but why isn't it shrinking ?

Because nothing is telling it to ignore it's content.

```css
p {
  background: pink;
  height: 9000px;
  margin:0;
}

[green] {
  min-height: 0; /* ignore content */
}
```

```html
<html style="height:100%;font-size:35px;">

<body style="height:100%; margin:0;">
  <div style="width:80%; height:100%; background:red; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
    1
    <div green style="width:80%; height:100%; background:green; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
      2
      <div style="width:50%; height:100%; background:blue; overflow:auto;">
        <p>long content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

By telling the green element to ignore it's content it will shrink-to-fit inside the red element and the blue element will follow.

Comment: Setting min-height seemed to work great, thanks!  Do you have any suggested resources for understanding the behavior you describe in more detail?

Comment: You read about it in the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto